# Salesforce Static Resource Limit 250MB

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, staticresource

I am trying to install a managed package on a Salesforce org. But I get the Error Unable to install the Managed package due exceeding of Static resource limit.
Our org's static resource has reached around 350MB. But as per the Salesforce documentation an Org's static resource limit is 250MB. When I run a query I see the unmanaged static resource in the org as just 30MB. Is there any Salesforce documentation which shows the Salesforce static resource limit of 250MB is inclusive of both managed & unmanaged static resources? Need some good evidence to show it to my other team members.

Comment: Run the "Optimizer" functionality in setup. It produces a pdf with tons of useful hints and links. I know static res are checked too but don't remember if includes any links. Or if you prefer -interactive app, "back in my days" it was a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes see documentation below.  From my experience Managed Packages (including Salesforce managed packages) usually count for the most usage.

> Static resources in managed packages do count against the 250 MB per Org limit. Attempting to install a managed package that would cause your Org to exceed the static resources limit will cause the package install to fail.

Knowledge Article Number
000316981

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000316981&type=1